# Standard way to generate HTML prototypes?

Tags: html, user-experience, prototyping

I used to get PSD files and generate HTML prototypes from them which are supposed to be exact replica of these PSDs. The process I follow is simplest one generate **plain HTML pages** for each PSD.
But I have seen some of the prototypes being generated from **server-side includes** (like PHP pages). Benefit of using server side includes is that you don't have to repeat header, footers and side panels for each page. But in this case, anyone who want to run pages needs to setup the server and then execute these pages on server.

I want to know, what are some recommended practices to generate prototypes? Or what are the steps followed generally in case of big projects?

Comment: Please see this closed question that I asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450365/whats-the-best-platform-for-a-static-website

Answer (score 1):

First of all there is no standard way to generate HTML prototypes, it depends on the complexity of the problem, the target audience and what the target audience expects from the HTML prototype.

1. Look and Feel with 2-3 pages - the HTML from PSDs may be sufficient or even from MS Word, Viso or Powerpoint
2. 5-10 pages - HTML prototypes can be generated from wire framing tools like Axure (http://www.axure.com/)
3. More complex proof of concept prototypes - server side programming tools may be used. There are some application generation tools which you give a data model and they generate code for a navigable UI.

The call on which tool to use depends on what your customers/clients expect